# Find the reCAPTCHA element and click on it -- Python + Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, recaptcha, webdriverwait

I need some help.
There is URL: https://www.inipec.gov.it/cerca-pec/-/pecs/companies.
I need to click checkbox Captcha:
[image]

My code is look like:

```
import os, urllib.request, requests, datetime, time, random, ssl, json, codecs, csv, urllib
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chromedriver = "chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.inipec.gov.it/cerca-pec/-/pecs/companies")
driver.switch_to_default_content()
element = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('iframe')[1]
driver.switch_to_frame(element)

driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="recaptcha-anchor"]/div[1]').click()
```

During the execution, there is an error:

> driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="recaptcha-anchor"]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KluDR.jpg)').click()
>   AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Please, help to fix it.

Comment: You need to use `find_element_by_xpath` for single web element.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Solution update (11-Feb-2020)

Using the following set of binaries:

- *Selenium v3.141.0*
- *ChromeDriver v80.0*
- *Chrome Version 80.0*

You can use the following updated block of code as a solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.inipec.gov.it/cerca-pec/-/pecs/companies")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[name^='a-'][src^='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='recaptcha-anchor']"))).click()
```

---

### Original solution

Within the URL `https://www.inipec.gov.it/cerca-pec/-/pecs/companies` to invoke `click()` on the **reCAPTCHA** checkbox you need to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following solution:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
  driver.get("https://www.inipec.gov.it/cerca-pec/-/pecs/companies")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[name^='a-'][src^='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='recaptcha-checkbox goog-inline-block recaptcha-checkbox-unchecked rc-anchor-checkbox']/div[@class='recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark']"))).click()
  ```

Comment: @MobrineHayde Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Still doesnt work: `ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <iframe>..</iframe> is not clickable at point (277, 36). Other element would receive the click`

Comment: @AbdulKarim Try


`driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='recaptcha-checkbox goog-inline-block recaptcha-checkbox-unchecked rc-anchor-checkbox']/div[@class='recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark']"))))`

for the last line

Comment: Are you getting extra image identification captchas when clicking the checkbox with Selenium? I think it's odd that it doesn't happen when I click with my regular Chrome browser, but always occurs with Selenium.

Comment: It seems that this solution doesn't work with captcha v3. Is there any way out? There is no clickable span in this case.

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly with reCAPTCHA v2

Answer (score 0):

**I resolved this, you can try this with your landing website url.**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import SessionNotCreatedException

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"download.default_directory": download_dir}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver", chrome_options = options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo")

driver.maximize_window()
price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='g-recaptcha']")
price_content = price.get_attribute('innerHTML')
start = str(price_content).find(";k=")+len(";k=")
end = str(price_content).find("&amp;co")
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').style.display = '';")
recaptcha_text_area = driver.find_element_by_id("g-recaptcha-response")
    
recaptcha_text_area.clear()
recaptcha_text_area.send_keys(price_content[start:end])
    #.....................................................................................
    
button = driver.find_element_by_id("recaptcha-demo-submit")
```