# Can you click the reCapatcha 'Audio Challenge' Button Using Selenium + Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, recaptcha, google-speech-to-text-api

The problem I am having is iframe elements say theyre not clickable by selenium when trying to reference xPath

I saw this original stackoverflow:

[Find the reCAPTCHA element and click on it -- Python + Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53917157/find-the-recaptcha-element-and-click-on-it-python-selenium/53917309)

But the solution given:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.inipec.gov.it/cerca-pec/-/pecs/companies")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[name^='a-'][src^='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='recaptcha-anchor']"))).click()
```

gave me this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="recaptcha-audio-button"]'))).click()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\bot\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

I'm not sure it is possible but if so please let me know or alternatives...