# Python selenium doesn't click?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, webdriver

In python I have:

```
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get("https://ug3.technion.ac.il/rishum/login")
driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys(user_id)
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn btn-success").click()
```

But for some reason it doesn't click on sign bottom (the green one) how can I fix this?

Update: from the comments I got I understand that I need to solve the captcha thus I want now to click on the Audio bottom, in a tutorial they wrote:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
frames = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]").find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(frames[0])
delay()

# click on audio challenge
driver.find_element_by_id("recaptcha-audio-button").click()
```

but that didn't work for me.

Comment: This site uses a [captcha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA). Please read more about it in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58872451/how-to-bypass-google-captcha-with-selenium-and-python).

Comment: @costaparas I know, I want to click directly on sign in bottom how can I do it?

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-success").click()` will correctly click on the button -- but that won't solve the captcha problem. Captchas are designed to combat automation

Comment: @costaparas thanks, please see my updated post

Comment: That's an interesting approach. Have you tried instead the steps in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53917157/find-the-recaptcha-element-and-click-on-it-python-selenium/53917309#53917309)?