# Bypass captcha selenium python

Tags: python, xpath

Heyyy ^^ I am coding on selenium python from Jupiterlab except that I have a problem. I'm coding a robot to find a graphics card on AMD's site for my son's birthday. However, there comes a time when you have to complete a captcha. I can't find any way around it despite my internet research. How can I do ? This is a captcha where you have to select images.
(selenium, webdriver, python).
Thank you ^^

Comment: Captchas were meant to not be easily solvable by programs.  It's possible that there is no way around it.  With that said, the answers to this question have a couple of tips for avoiding captchas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58872451/how-can-i-bypass-the-google-captcha-with-selenium-and-python

Comment: J'ai bien vu ce topic déjà mais le soucis c'est que dans mon code ça ouvre un nouveau navigateur et les cookies ne sont jamais stockés

Comment: Vous avez essayé les autres solutions, comme changer le "user agent" et utilisant `time.sleep`?  Il y a aussi quelques réponses qui disent comment cliquer sur le captcha (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53917157/find-the-recaptcha-element-and-click-on-it-python-selenium/53917309#53917309).  Je crois que, meme si les cookies ne sont jamais stockés, vous pouvez les utiliser avec `driver.add_cookie` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058462/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver/15058521#15058521).  Désolé pour mon mauvais français, ce n'est pas ma langue maternelle

Comment: Sorry I forgot to translate ^^. How else do you know how not to open a browser with the program but only open a tab in the active browser? that would allow me to avoid this problem with cookies and to be already connected to the site.