# Selenium can't find element in any way

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, element

**I am trying to fill out a login form with python code.**
For that I need to click submit as the last step.

But Selenium can't find the submit button, wether by ID, Class, CSS Selector or Name.

Here is my full code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

website_link = "https://wildfall.net/wp-admin/"
username = "xxxx"
password = "xxxx"

element_for_username = "user_login"
element_for_password = "user_pass"
element_for_submit = "wp-submit"

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get((website_link))

time.sleep(5)

username_element = browser.find_element(By.ID, element_for_username)
username_element.send_keys(username)
password_element = browser.find_element(By.ID, element_for_password)
password_element.send_keys(password)
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[name^='a-'][src^='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?']")))
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='recaptcha-checkbox goog-inline-block recaptcha-checkbox-unchecked rc-anchor-checkbox']/div[@class='recaptcha-checkbox-border']"))).click()
time.sleep(10)
submit_element = browser.find_element(By.ID, element_for_submit)
submit_element.click()
```

Part where the error occurs

```
submit_element = browser.find_element(By.ID, element_for_submit)
submit_element.click()
```

Here is the error

```
>>> submit_element = browser.find_element(By.ID, element_for_submit)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 857, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 435, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="wp-submit"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.63)
```

I don't understand why it can't find the button, as it finds all others. It's also no iframe so can't be because of that.
Maybe I just don't find the correct Name/Class/ID for the Button but there's not much to choose from, so I'm lost at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You switched to the iframe, you have to switch back. Try using:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score 0):

As `@facuew` correctly pointed out, once you [click on the reCAPTCHA checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53917309/7429447), to click on the element <kbd>Anmelden</kbd> you have to switch to the default content.

Your optimized code block can be:

```
driver.get('https://wildfall.net/wp-admin/')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#user_login"))).send_keys("username@stackoverflow.com")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#user_pass").send_keys("simplyGamic")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title=reCAPTCHA]")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.recaptcha-checkbox-border"))).click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#wp-submit"))).click()
```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: wildfall]