# How to click on this button with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

HTML:

```
<button type="submit" class="button primary g-recaptcha" 
data-sitekey="6LdSmG4cAAAAAAOarRxGIhehvv4sPgVeF-vRi-Jqb" 
data-callback="onSubmit">Avanti</button>
```

Attempt 1:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 
"/html/body/main/div/section[1]/form/button")))
.click()
```

Attempt 2:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 
"//[@class='button primary g-recaptcha' and @type='submit']")))
.click()
```

Answer (score 2):

To click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.button.primary.g-recaptcha[data-callback='onSubmit']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='button primary g-recaptcha' and text()='Avanti']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Update

Presumably, it's a [recaptcha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53917309/7429447) element and generally they resides within [**iframes**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447). So you need to [`switch_to.frame()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47771879/7429447) first as follows:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(By.ID,"id_of_iframe"))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.button.primary.g-recaptcha[data-callback='onSubmit']"))).click()
```

Comment: I keep getting the same error.
sorry something went wrong in chromedriver.exe