# Can't Find Element Inside iframe

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, recaptcha, captcha

I want to get the data-sitekey, but it is inside the iframe.

I only can get the element in class="container", can't find the element insde of it.

How can I get the data-sitekey?
[image: HTML]

```
driver.get(url)
driver.switch_to.frame("main-iframe")

container= driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'container')
print(container)

time.sleep(2)

captcha = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'g-recaptcha')
print(captcha)
```

Comment: Try to use [Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#waits) instead of `time.sleep`

Comment: `data_sitekey = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "g-recaptcha"))).get_attribute("data-sitekey")`
`print(data_sitekey)`



Also Can't

Comment: can you confirm the url?

Comment: yes i can find the container, but can't find anything under container

Answer (score 0):

The [reCAPTCHA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53917309/7429447) element is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447)

[image: reCAPTCHA_frame]

---

### Solution

To extract the value of the *`data-sitekey`* attribute you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447).
- You can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#main-iframe")))
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.g-recaptcha"))).get_attribute("data-sitekey"))
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='main-iframe']"))).get_attribute("data-sitekey"))
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='g-recaptcha']")))
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: sorry i don't understand how can i get it...
I have already get in iframe
`driver.switch_to.frame("main-iframe")`

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: [21884:21888:0813/231822.516:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(486)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\repo\concert\concert.py", line 136, in <module>
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='container']//div[@class='g-recaptcha']")))
  File "C:\Users\leung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 90, in until    
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: [21020:13200:0813/232742.194:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(486)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\repo\concert\concert.py", line 136, in <module>
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='g-recaptcha']")))
  File "C:\Users\leung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 90, in until    
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in Selenium Room.

Comment: or i give you the url to try?
https://premier.hkticketing.com/

Comment: I don't find any `iframe` even within the [website](https://premier.hkticketing.com/)

Comment: I just find you in Selenium Room

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get that information:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as Firefox_Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t

firefox_options = Firefox_Options()

# firefox_options.add_argument("--width=1280")
# firefox_options.add_argument("--height=720")
# firefox_options.headless = True

driverService = Service('chromedriver/geckodriver')

browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=driverService, options=firefox_options)

url = 'https://premier.hkticketing.com/'
browser.get(url) 
t.sleep(5)
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='main-iframe']")))
print('switched')
t.sleep(5)
element_x = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='g-recaptcha']"))  )
print(element_x.get_attribute('data-sitekey'))
```

Result  printed in terminal:

```
switched
6Ld38BkUAAAAAPATwit3FXvga1PI6iVTb6zgXw62
```

Setup is for linux/Firefox/geckodriver, but you can adapt it to your own system, just mind the imports, and the code after defining the browser.

Selenium docs: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/