# Selenium stealth not working, website still sending 403 error

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-stealth

The website redirect me to a captcha page (which is fine) but doesn't let me complete the captcha, sending a 403 response which is blocking the load of the captcha widget so I cannot send it to 2captcha workers. Tried VPN, tried switching network to my friend's house and I still get blocked. Is there any error in the code? Could be the **Chromium version** (**Chromium 104.0.5112.79 snap**) ?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium_stealth import stealth
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
# options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path="/snap/chromium/2051/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")

stealth(driver,
        languages=["en-US", "en"],
        vendor="Google Inc.",
        platform="Win32",
        webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
        renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline=True,
        )

url = "https://www.ticketmaster.de/event/nfl-munich-game-seattle-seahawks-tampa-bay-buccaneers-tickets/467425?language=en-us"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

- Option 1: you should try to clear you cookies, you are probably fallen in a black list.
- Option 2: the website detect selenium, in that case you can go to this question : [Can a website detect when you are using Selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver)

Comment: I am on ubuntu and running the perl command in the terminal gave me this error: Can't do inplace edit on /snap/chromium/2051/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver: Cannot make temp name: Read-only file system.

Answer (score 0):

Not that super clear why the [website](https://www.ticketmaster.de/event/nfl-munich-game-seattle-seahawks-tampa-bay-buccaneers-tickets/467425?language=en-us) redirect you to a [reCAPTCHA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53917309/7429447) page. However with almost similar configuration using *chrome=104.0* and [*chromedriver=104.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=104.0.5112.79/) , I can access the page perfecto.

- Code block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
  from selenium_stealth import stealth
  import time

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)

  # Selenium Stealth settings
  stealth(driver,
          languages=["en-US", "en"],
          vendor="Google Inc.",
          platform="Win32",
          webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
          renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
          fix_hairline=True,
          )

  driver.get('https://www.ticketmaster.de/event/nfl-munich-game-seattle-seahawks-tampa-bay-buccaneers-tickets/467425?language=en-us') # not detected
  driver.save_screenshot("ticketmaster")
  ```
- Screenshot:

[image: ticketmaster]

---

However, the second time I try to access the same page I I face the ***Pardon the Interruption*** page:

[image: PardonTheInterruption]

which essentially implies the navigation is blocked.

---

### References

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [Can a website detect when you are using Selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70133896/7429447)

Comment: Any ideas on why it blocks it on the 2nd time?

Comment: Here's the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62520191/7429447) discussion all about.

Comment: I'm trying all the solution listed. Unfortunately, so far, no result. Still getting blocked

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in the Selenium Chat Room.