# Unable to click on "Sign In" button with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, recaptcha, webdriverwait

I'm trying to automate a login with a user and password on a website, which is this one :

https://www.esselunga.it/area-utenti/applicationCheck?appName=esselungaEcommerce&daru=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.esselungaacasa.it%3A443%2Fecommerce%2Fnav%2Fauth%2Fsupermercato%2Fhome.html%3F&loginType=light

I managed to insert the user and the password trough Selenium, but I can't click on the "Accedi" button, which is the Italian word for "Sign In".

HTML:

```
<div>
   <button value="Accedi" type="submit">Accedi</button>
</div>
```

I tried the following python code:

1st try:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/form[1]/div/button"))).click()
```

2nd try:

```
button = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="Accedi")
```

3rd try:

```
button = driver.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value="Accedi")
button.click()
```

But without success.
Can you please help me with this personal project?

Comment: try this for xpath -> //button[@value='Accedi'] 
and I have noticed it showing reCAPTCHA isn't causing any issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
# Needed libs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

#Open the browser
driver = webdriver.Edge()
url = 'https://www.esselunga.it/area-utenti/applicationCheck?appName=esselungaEcommerce&daru=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.esselungaacasa.it%3A443%2Fecommerce%2Fnav%2Fauth%2Fsupermercato%2Fhome.html%3F&loginType=light'
driver.get(url)

user = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, f"gw_username")))
user.send_keys('User@gmai.com')
user = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, f"gw_password")))
user.send_keys('password')
login_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"//button[@value='Accedi']")))
login_button.click()
time.sleep(10)
```

But I see a big problem here...and the problem is that you have a captcha. With the hints I give you will solve the problem of clicking into the element, but in the moment you need to pass the captcha...that will be a different topic because captchas are created for avoiding bots (Selenium is a bot managing your browser).

For the problem with the captcha you can check this other answer: [Captctha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58872451/how-can-i-bypass-the-google-captcha-with-selenium-and-python)

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

To click on <kbd>Accedi</kbd> first you have to click on the [reCAPTCHA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53917309/7429447) checkbox which is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the [reCAPTCHA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58876531/7429447) *element to be clickable*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49775808/7429447) for <kbd>Accedi</kbd> *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.esselunga.it/area-utenti/applicationCheck?appName=esselungaEcommerce&daru=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.esselungaacasa.it%3A443%2Fecommerce%2Fnav%2Fauth%2Fsupermercato%2Fhome.html%3F&loginType=light')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#accettaTuttiCookie"))).click()
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#gw_username").send_keys("LeonardoVarè@stackoverflow.com")
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#gw_password").send_keys("LeonardoVarè")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title='reCAPTCHA']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span#recaptcha-anchor"))).click()
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[value='Accedi']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```